# link_to not working in script/console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
// using Rails 2.3.5

//routes.rb
map.resources :users, 

>> user = User.first
>> helper.link_to user.name, user
```

I am getting nil error. I thought the above code should work. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe that url generation depends on a controller and maybe a http request, but I don't know how you'd go about that in the console.

Answer (score 32):

The problem is that `link_to` uses `url_for` which needs an incoming url host. You can use `app.url_for` in the console to fake it like so:

```
helper.link_to user.name, app.url_for(user)
```